# POST request not working in swift3 with alamofire

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

I am  using Alamofire for calling my API .

below is is the code.

```
func alamofirePost() {
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "content-type": "x-www-form-urlencoded"]
let todosEndpoint: String = "http://54.244.108.186:4000/api/post_upc"
let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["UPC": codeTextView.text, "DATE_TIME":         currentTime() ]
print("i am in alamo")
Alamofire.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: newTodo ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers )
.responseJSON { response in
guard response.result.error == nil else {
// got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
print(response)
print(response.result.error!)
return
}
```

when i call the function , it is trying to inserting null values in the database

```
INSERT INTO `UPC`(`UPC`,`DATE_TIME`) VALUES (NULL,NULL)
```

Below is the response when i do in postman app.

[image]

can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in your Postman request you are POSTing your body as `x-www-form-urlencoded` but in your Swift example you are specifying that header as well. BUT you're actually submitting your POST body as a JSON payload. In contrast, your Postman request is a set of key/value pairs.

Additionally, the two keys appear to be named differently from your Swift example and your Postman example.

Swift uses `UPC` and `DATE_TIME` while Postman has `upc_app` and `dttm_app` so at a minimum you'll want to ensure you send along what your API expects

Comment: Great Cody . Thanks. I researched around and got the solution.